# how to arrange data in cloudant NOSQL data base according to time stamp

Tags: database, cloudant, nosql

i have connected nodered to Watson iot platform using raspberry pi, now Watson extends to Cloudant NOSQL databse, the datas are  arranged in random manner.When i send getrequest from external app the datas are random, how do i fetch data in order according to timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your documents contain a field with a timestamp value you could create a view and query it (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/creating_views.html#views-mapreduce-).

CouchDB/Cloudant returns view results sorted by the key that's defined in the view definition. Simple example, assuming all docs include a field named `date_sent` representing a timestamp value:

```
{
    ...
    "date_sent": "2017-02-09T21:37:20.731Z",
    ...
}
```

- Create a view (replace the placeholders `$...` as appropriate)

  ```
  PUT https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/_design/$DD_NAME HTTP/1.1

  {
   "views" : {
     "docs_sorted_by_date" : {
      "map" : "function(doc) { emit(doc.date_sent,1);  }"
     }
   }
  }
  ```
- Query the view

  ```
  GET https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/_design/$DD_NAME/_view/docs_sorted_by_date HTTP/1.1
  ```